# VTK - Interacting with multiple objects

Tags: c++, image-processing, render, vtk

I am fairly new to VTK and I really enjoy using it.

Now, I want to interact with multiple objects independently. For example, if I have 5 objects in a render window, I want to only move, rotate and interact with the one selected object; whilst the rest of the 4 objects stay where it is.

At the moment, the camera is doing the magic and as I rotate the independent object, other objects move at the same time and I don't want that to happen.

I also want to store all the objects in memory.

I intend to use C++.

This is my sort of class structure...

```
class ScreenObjects
{
   vtkActor (LinkedList); // I intend on using a linkedlist to store all the actors

   public:
   ScreenObjects(); // Constructor. Initializes vtkActor to null.
   void readSTLFile(); // Reads the STL File
   bool setObject(); // Sets current object, so you can only interact with the selected object
}
```

I am missing quite a lot of functions and detail in my class, as I don't know what else to include that would be of use. I was also thinking of joining two objects together, but again, I don't know how to incorporate that in my class; any information on that would be appreciated.

Would really appreciate it if I could be given ideas. This is something of big interest to me and it would really mean a lot to me, and I mean this deep down from my heart.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should read some tutorials and presentations like this one for example:
http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~cutler/classes/visualization/F10/lectures/03_interaction.pdf

I say that cause it looks like you're currently just moving the camera.

Then you should look into the VTK examples. They are very helpful for all VTK classes.
Especially for your problem have a look at:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/Picking

Basicly you have to create a **vtkRenderWindowInteractor** derived class to get the mouse events (onMouseDown,onMouseUp,onMouseMove,...).

And a **vtkPropPicker** to shoot a ray from your mouse position into the 3D view and get the vtkActor.

Now you can store onMouseDown inside your vtkRenderWindowInteractor derived class the vtkActor you'd like to move and the currentMouse position. When the user release the mouse (onMouseUp) just get the new mouse position and use the difference of the onMouseDown/onMouseUp positions to modify the vtkActor position.

Comment: Darko, thanks for the suggestion :), it means a lot. In terms of interacting with the vtkActor using the vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor, how would I go about using matrices? Ideally, I want to use matrices to rotate and translate the vtkActors? Also, in terms of storage to memory, I was thinking of having a class that takes multiple instances of the vtkActor class. I want to ideally store multiple actors in memory, so that they can be seen in the render window

Comment: You can put vtkActors in an std::vector or something like that with no problem. To use a transform matrix, you can use vtkProp3D::SetUserTransform (available to vtkActor*, because vtkActor is derived from vtkProp3D) http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProp3D.html#aac7f621f0a3666a29d21b5087919797a